# Using "since" or "because" in a question

Tags: word-usage

In the following question, I think that it is wrong to use "because," and instead the word "since" must be used, but I want to check with other native speakers.

> Can I go with you, because I finished my homework?

Am I right? Either way, can you explain to me why this is or isn't correct?

(I asked a similar question before, but I think I've found some clarity and wanted to rephrase my question here.)

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not make things clear.

**Because** links phrases/clauses/sentences, with one part giving the reason for the other part.

**Since** can be used either of time or of reason/cause.

For example, you can say either:

> I took my umbrella with me **because** rain seemed likely.

Or:

> I took my umbrella with me **since** rain seemed likely.

Here **since** is employed in the sense of **because** - meaning **for this reason**.

**Since is also used to specify something that has or has not happened from a specific point (day, month, year, season, period) in time.

> I have not seen them since Christmas.

In your example you are implying that having finished your homework, you are now free to accompany someone. But you do not make this clear. To be clear, using either **because** or **since**, you might say:

> **Since** (or **because**) I have now finished my homework and am free, may I accompany you?

You could also reverse the sentence and begin with **May I accompany you....**

Answer (score 0):

You are making a question and a statement

> Can i come with you,since i finished my homework?

is the correct way

Your using because:

> Are you going to drink your tea?,because it's getting cold.

The word because in you sentence does not sound accurate and takes a longer breathe to say. And sounds like your saying "if i only finish my homework can i come with you" like your asking for a routine to happen every time that person is leaving and your done with your homework